# Define Path in Power Query

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I had recorded a Macro to merge 2 txt files from a folder.

Macro Looks like this:

---

ActiveWorkbook.Queries("test").Delete

ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="test", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""C:\Users\test\Desktop\folder\test.txt"")

---

I am planning to copy the excel to a folder that contains the .txt files

How to replace the path C:\Users\test\Desktop\folder\test.txt to use current working folder of worksheet + "\test.txt"?

I am deleting the query in the VBA script to avoid the error "A Query with the name test already exists"

Comment: If you're moving the Excel file which is running the macro into the same folder as the target file, you could use `Thisworkbook.Path` to help build the full path to your target file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without VBA

Only remember that if you change the folder where the files are saved, you need to refresh the query

Steps:

1. In a cell put this formula: `=LEFT(CELL("filename";A1);FIND("[";CELL("filename";A1))-1)`

[image]

2. Assign a name range to that cell e.g. `CurrentFolder`

[image]

3. With that cell selected, click on Data | From Table / Range

[image]

4. Delete the automatically applied steps (*depends on your configuration*)

[image]

5. Select the path, right click it and select Drill down

[image]

```
*Now your query should output just the workbook path*
```

[image]

6. Create a new query that extracts the data from the folder / file
7. In the source step, replace the path (including the quotes) with `CurrentFolder`

[image]

Let me know if it works

Comment: Awesome. Remember to mark the andwer with the tickbox so others may find them too